# Node.js "Callback is already called". But there are no any other callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, asynccallback

I'm searching forum all the day, but I can't solve my problem. Im using NodeJS and async.waterfall to make some API requests.
Same structure works for me, but not there;

```
    async.waterfall([
       function (callback) {
           callback(null, latitude, longitude, callback);
       },
       getGeoNames,   
   ],
   function (err, result) {
      console.log("ok");
   })
```

and here are function getGeoNames with error

```
function getGeoNames(latitude, longitude, callback) {
    var countryKey = 'country';
    var stateKey = 'administrative_area_level_1';

    var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+latitude+","+longitude;


    request({
        url: url,
        json: true
    }, function (error, response, body) {

            var adresses = body.results[0].address_components;
            var geo = {};
            for (var i = 0, len = adresses.length; i < len; i++) {
                var adress = adresses[i];
                //console.log(adress);
                if ( adress.types[0] == countryKey ) {
                    geo.country = adress.long_name;
                    if (geo.state !== undefined) break;
                }
                else if ( adress.types[0] == stateKey ) {
                    geo.state = adress.long_name;
                    if (geo.country !== undefined) break;
                }
            };
            return callback(null, geo); // ERROR HERE <-----------------
    })
}
```

Can request function run callback() function , so it was runned before?
I tried without "**return**", but it's the same.

> ```
>         if (fn === null) throw new Error("Callback was already called.");
>                          ^
> ```
>
> Error: Callback was already called.
>       at c:\Users\Serega\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:803:36
>       at Request._callback (c:\Users\Serega\WebstormProjects\untitled1\server.js:174:20)
>       at Request.self.callback (c:\Users\Serega\node_modules\request\request.js:200:22)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:172:7)
>       at Request. (c:\Users\Serega\node_modules\request\request.js:1067:10)
>       at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:169:7)
>       at IncomingMessage. (c:\Users\Serega\node_modules\request\request.js:988:12)
>       at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

PS: other waterfall functions works with request for me.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is here.

```
callback(null, latitude, longitude, callback);
```

You should not pass a callback as an argument.

Comment: Спасибо огромное - помогло :)